# Shapefiles not showing in OpenLayers using QGIS export to OpenLayers 3 plugin?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, openlayers, visualisation

I am new to GISs in general and I am working with QGIS to generate layers to be shown on OSM using OpenLayers.

My problem is the following:

I have multiple layers in a QGIS project and I want to export all of them to be displayed in OpenLayers.

To do that I used two methods:

1) Export to OpenLayers 3 plugin of QGIS

The exporting process is done without errors but when I try to visualize some layers they don't appear even when I hide the rest of the layers including the base OSM layer.

2) js-shapefile-to-geojson javascript API

This API converts shape files to geojson format but projecting them on an OSM map doesn't place them correctly.

They appear like a dot in a placement too far from the desired location.
However, when I tried to visualize the same layers that does not appear using the test page provided by the API I was able to visualize them.
So here the problem is to integrate the layers with OSM.

Are there any suggestions on how to visualize these layers using QGIS plugin ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: Export to OpenLayers 3 is now qgis2web. Do try that QGIS plugin to see if it works better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the Developer console?

Using the QGIS "Export to Openlayers 3 Plugin", I get a an error saying
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oe' of undefined" in ol.js, which I do not know how to fix.

An additional problem may be that the style variable is differently named in the layer_style file of the styles folder. To fix this, make sure the variable is named the same way - eg. *layer_style*, not *style_layer*, and that the style/layer_style.js file has the correct capital or lower case letters.